# Error in unit tests after yeoman gulp-angular projekt setup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, yeoman

...

got a problem with a problem setup.

I use yeoman and create my project with

```
yo gup-angular
```

After setup I start the unit testing with

```
gulp test
```

But it fails with:

```
PS P:\projects\test-logbook> gulp test
[15:15:14] Using gulpfile P:\projects\mydisk-logbook\gulpfile.js
[15:15:14] Starting 'scripts'...
[15:15:15] all files 14.08 kB
[15:15:15] Finished 'scripts' after 840 ms
[15:15:15] Starting 'test'...
28 09 2017 15:15:15.601:WARN [proxy]: proxy "\base\src\assets\" normalized to "\base\src\assets\/"
28 09 2017 15:15:15.665:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "P:/projects/mydisk-logbook/src/**/*.mock.js" does not match any file.
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (near '....info({ angularVersion: '...')
  at P:/projects/mydisk-logbook/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:4138


[15:15:18] 'test' errored after 2.69 s
[15:15:18] Error: Failed 1 tests.
    at P:\projects\mydisk-logbook\gulp\unit-tests.js:41:22
    at removeAllListeners (P:\projects\mydisk-logbook\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:336:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (P:\projects\mydisk-logbook\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:347:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1554:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

It failed in bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js, line 4138.

How to solve that error? What is my fail?

Regards
n00n

ps: Bower Update gets me this information

```
Please note that,
    angular-aria#1.5.11, angular-cookies#1.5.11, angular-messages#1.5.11, angular-mocks#1.5.11, angular-resource#1.5.11, angular-sanitize#1.5.11, angular-touch#1.5.11 depends on angular#1.5.11 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
    mydisk-logbook depends on angular#~1.5.3 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
    angular-material#1.0.9 depends on angular#^1.4.8 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
    angular-ui-router#0.2.18 depends on angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
    angular-toastr#1.5.0 depends on angular#>=1.3.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
    angular-animate#1.6.6 depends on angular#1.6.6 which resolved to angular#1.6.6
Resort to using angular#~1.5.3 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
Code incompatibilities may occur.

bower jquery                    extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: jquery#~2.1.4
```

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Those kind of issues are usually due to versions mismatch between angular libraries.
Are all of Angular's libs locked to the same version?

Comment: I am not sure. Sorry, for the delay, but we moved in another apartment, had no internet. You will find my packages, here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWGvMd